# Which stack is best for asking about profit payments of Adwords?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'd like to distribute Adwords profits to my users, but have no idea where to ask.

How could I structure this and how would the users then be categorised? Would they be categorised as employees or could I hand out cash rewards?

I'm only at the beginning stages of exploring this question. So apologies for the lack of detail.

Comment: Maybe WebMasters: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic but I would ask on their Meta first because I'm not sure this fits for them.

Comment: There is also a legal/financial aspect of this. To be honest I don't think it matters all that much where the money originated. So you could check out https://law.stackexchange.com/ or https://money.stackexchange.com/ as well. I don't visit those sites, so be sure to check their help center before posting there.

Comment: There are multiple aspects to this and some may fit better on one site while others fit better on the other. Webmasters an Law are obvious mentions for their parts, but check their help-centers first.